# Ajax redirect doesn't work same as ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, jquery

I have a javascript function that works as I would like :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function dofunction(dropdown) {
        debugger;
        for (i = 0; i < 194; i++) {
            if (dropdown[i].selected == true) {
                var Shrt_ttls = dropdown[i].value.toString();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/ProgramSummary/Details?titl=" + Shrt_ttls//,
                    //type: 'Post'
                });
                i = 195;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
</script>
```

The code redirects to the ProgramsummaryController to the Details method (in debug everything works fine and the correct value is passed to the method and the Details method looks like this

```
    public ActionResult Details(string titl)
    {
        using (var dc = new USP_Select_TRP_ProgramSummary_wShortNameDataContext())
        {
            string shrt_titles = titl;
            if (shrt_titles == null)
            {
                shrt_titles = "3DELRR";
            }
            return View(dc.usp_Select_TRP_ProgramSummary_wShortName(shrt_titles).Single());
        }
    }
```

The View is called and seems to be fine and returns to the _Layout.cshtml all seems fine but the Details View is not shown but instead the original Index view is shown. Where as if I use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Resource(s)", "Details", "ProgramSummary", new { titl = "3DELRR"})
```

The same events as before take place and instead of the Index view remaining the Details View appears. WHy does the first way not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
location.href = "/ProgramSummary/Details?titl=" + Shrt_ttls;
```

instead of Ajax, ajax is a request only in javascript, its not displayed by the browser unless you code it to.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `$.ajax` is making an ansynchronous javascript request to your controller action. Your controller is then returning a View (html) as a response. You need to take that html and do something with it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'whatever',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#sometarget').html(data);
    }
}
```

Also, since this is an AJAX request you should probably return a PartialView and not a full view in your controller:

```
return PartialView("SomePartialView", model);
```